# Relationship Parser Error in EE 2.10.1

Tags: relationships, php-errors

I'm opening this issue here on StackExchange because the folks at Ellis seem to be incapable of resolving this issue https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20748/relationship-parents-php-parse-error-ignores-condition

If there are any PHP gurus out there who can troubleshoot this issue, please weigh in. PHP is not my forte.

This is what I've found:

```
{parents field="doctors_locations" limit="1"}
    {if parents:doctors_locations:total_results >= 1}
        <a href="/search/doctors?category:affiliation=78|79|80|218&amp;child:doctors_locations={entry_id}&amp;orderby_sort=doctors_last_name|asc" class="button button-green mb30">View Doctors</a>
    {if:else}
        {!-- RETURN NOTHING --}
    {/if}
{/parents}
```

This returns more than 100 PHP errors in a search results page with 10 results. This is the most common error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: 66

Filename: relationship_parser/Tree_builder.php

Line Number: 544
```

Towards the end of the errors, I found this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 4529

Filename: relationship_parser/Parser.php

Line Number: 52
```

And finally this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /MYPATH/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 479
```

If I remove the conditionals like this:

```
{parents field="doctors_locations" limit="1"}
    <a href="/search/doctors?category:affiliation=78|79|80|218&amp;child:doctors_locations={entry_id}&amp;orderby_sort=doctors_last_name|asc" class="button button-green mb30">View Doctors</a>
{/parents}
```

I only get 3 PHP errors that are basically the same:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 4530

Filename: relationship_parser/Parser.php

Line Number: 52
```

The only difference between the three errors is that the Undefined offset increments from 4528 to 4530.